# reconstruction: why undistort image AND normalize coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

From the Tutorial: https://programtalk.com/vs2/?source=python/8176/opencv-python-blueprints/chapter4/scene3D.py
I don't understand why they first **undistort the images**

```
 # undistort the images
 self.img1 = cv2.undistort(self.img1, self.K, self.d)
 self.img2 = cv2.undistort(self.img2, self.K, self.d)
```

and: **Compute the Essential Matrix**

```
def _find_fundamental_matrix(self):
        self.F, self.Fmask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(self.match_pts1,
                                                    self.match_pts2,
                                                    cv2.FM_RANSAC, 0.1,0.99)

def _find_essential_matrix(self):
        self.E = self.K.T.dot(self.F).dot(self.K)
```

and also **Normalize the coordinates:**

```
first_inliers = []
second_inliers = []
for i in range(len(self.Fmask)):
    if self.Fmask[i]:
        # normalize and homogenize the image coordinates
        first_inliers.append(self.K_inv.dot([self.match_pts1[i][0],
                             self.match_pts1[i][1], 1.0]))
        second_inliers.append(self.K_inv.dot([self.match_pts2[i][0],
                              self.match_pts2[i][1], 1.0]))
```

Shouldn't it be ***either or***? Or do I have some wrong understanding here?
Can please somone help me on that?

Comment: Why do you think this should be either/or? What do you think undistorting and normalizing coordinates, respectively, do? Without knowing that, it's kind of like answering "Why do you turn the music on AND set the navigation coordinates when you start your car?" There could be a good question there (maybe you're saying that voiceover navigation cutting out the music every few km is annoying), or it could be a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: My understanding was, that undistorting the image leads to the normalized original point coordinates. So that there would be no more need to normalize the coordinates?

Comment: They're two different things. See the Wikipedia articles on [distortion (optics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29) and [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). (Normalizing is an even simpler thing you do before homogenizing to make the math easier.)

Answer (score 1):

The first step, [`undistort`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), does a number of things to reverse the typical warping caused by small camera lenses. See the Wikipedia article on [distortion (optics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29) for more background.

The last step, homogenizing the coordinates, is a completely different thing. The Wikipedia article on [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) explains it, but the basic idea is that you add in an extra fake axis that lets you do all affine and projective transformations with chained simple matrix multiplication and then just project back to 3D at the end. Normalizing is just a step you do to make that math easier—basically, you want your extra coordinate to start off as 1.0 (multiply by the inverse of the projective norm).

Comment: thanks. But refering to the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d about the distortion at  undistortPoints() : "normalized" means that the coordinates do not depend on the camera matrix) and then the normalizing with K_inv does the same thing doesn't it?

Comment: @Luisa Those docs don't say that it normalizes. The docs for the next function down do talk about normalizing—but even there, it's only with respect to rotation about the camera (not, e.g., translation), and also, it computes the transformation that would take normalized distorted points to normalized undistorted points; if you didn't start with normalized distorted points, you won't end up with normalized undistorted points.

Comment: okay, so they mean it is normalized _and_ undistorted then? Also the normalized coordinates from the tutorial are just for computational purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for normalization is explained at page-107 of [Multi-View Geometry (Hartley and Zisserman)](ftp://vista.eng.tau.ac.il/dropbox/SimonKolotov-Thesis/Articles/%5BRichard_Hartley_Andrew_Zisserman%5D_Multiple_View_G%28BookFi.org%29.pdf). The normalization is required in addition to the un-distortion.

If are using raw pixel values in homogeneous coordinates, the Z-coordinate which is 1 will be small compared to the X and Y co-coordinates. Eg: (X=320, Y=220, Z=1).

But if the homogenized coordinates are the image pixel positions normalized to a standard range, ie -1.0 to 1.0, then we are talking about coordinate values all of whom are kind of in the same range , Eg: (0.75, -0.89, 1.0).

If the image coordinates are of dramatically different ranges(as in the unnormalized case), then the DLT matrix produced will have a bad condition number,  and consequently small variations in input image pixel positions, could produce wide variations in the result.

Please see page 107 for a very good explanation.